# material-ui : Chrome unexpected autofill <TextField <Autocomplete

Tags: google-chrome, material-ui

I'm trying to prevent Chrome to autofill all my fields. I'm adding autocomplete='off' to the input of both the TextField and the Autocomplete as following:

```
<TextField
   autoComplete={'off'}

<Autocomplete
  renderInput={params => {

            const inputProps = params.inputProps;
            (inputProps as any).autocomplete = 'off';

            return ...
```

Unless I did not pay attention carefully it seems Chrome is recently ignoring this 'off' value for autofill.

I understand that I can use any other value like for example 'chrome-off' to prevent that autofill but is that the right way to do? Will it work in Firefox / Edge ?

Shouldn't Material-UI propose a high level configuration saying for example autofill=false?